# In Python, how can I use an attribute as both and attribute and a method/callable?

Tags: python

This is kindof an experiment. I'm interested in an API that supports both of these syntaxes:

```
obj.thing
```

--> returns default value

```
obj.thing(2, 'a')
```

--> returns value derived from *args and **kwargs

"`thing`" is the same object in both cases; I'd like the calling of thing to be optional (or implicit, if there are not () after it).

I tried over-riding __repr__, but that's just the visual representation of the the object itself, and what is *actually returned* is an instance of the containing object (here, 'obj'). So, no good.

I'm thinking that there would be an attribute set on an object that was a callable (don't care if it's an instance, a def, or just __call__ on the object) that has enough default values:

```
class CallableDefault(object):
    __call__(self, num=3, letter="z"):
        return letter * num

class DumbObject(object):
    foo = CallableDefault()

obj = DumbObject()
```

so, ideally, doing `obj` alone would return "zzz", but one could also do `obj(7,'a')` and get 'aaaaaaa'.

I'm thinking decorators might be the way to do this, but I'm not great with decorators. One could override the getattr() call on the containing class, but that would mean that it has to be in a containing class that supports this feature.

Comment: What do you want to get if a default value is a callable?

Comment: how about you just add `()` and call it as a normal method?

Comment: JBernardo, umm, yeah, I know how to do that. It's not my question, obviously.

Comment: Liori, no special behavior; what is returned is returned. But I agree with the implicit question/observation, this would indeed be messy because it would imply thing()() is actually happening if you called thing(). Though this is an experiment, I would suppose that thing() would still call the __call__ method "normally".

Comment: But you can't do it the way you want. Either you get the first (with `@property`) or the later form (with a normal function)

Comment: @JBernardo: sure he can do it the way he wants -- whether on not it's a good idea is a different question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe could work, but notice that now the value of the attribute is constrained to be an object of your `CallableDefault` class.  This probably won't be very useful.

I strongly suggest that you don't try to do this.  For one thing, you're spending a lot of time trying to trick Python into doing something it doesn't want to do.  For another, the users of your API will be confused because it acts differently than every other Python code they've ever seen.  They will be confused.

Write a Python API that works naturally in Python.

Comment: No, I don't think it could work because there's no way to a `__getattr__` method knows that he'll call the function later or not.

Comment: This is right; there's no facility in Python (that I'm aware of) where a callable can "know" what called it, or what will happen later.

Comment: When I say, "what you describe could work," I mean the attribute could have an object that is useful, and also provides a `__call__` method.  As I pointed out, the value could only be of a type like this, it couldn't be a string or an int, etc.

Comment: It could be a `str` or `int` subclass, though, per my example.

Comment: I chose this as "the answer" because I'm satisfied that it was not a good idea. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3):

What happens when you do either

```
obj.thing
```

or

```
obj.thing(2, 'a')
```

is Python goes looking for `thing` on `obj`; once it has `thing` it either returns it (first case above), or calls it with the parameters (second case) -- the critical point being that the call does not happen until *after* the attribute is retrieved -- and the containing class has no way of knowing if the thing it returns will be called or not.

You could add a `__call__` method to every type you might use this way, but that way lies madness.

**Update**

Well, as long as you're comfortable with insanity, you could try something like this:

```
class CallableStr(str):
    def __call__(self, num, letter):
        return num*letter

class CallableInt(int):
    def __call__(self, num, pow):
        return num ** pow

class Tester(object):
    wierd = CallableStr('zzz')
    big = CallableInt(3)

t = Tester()
print repr(t.wierd)
print repr(t.wierd(7, 'a'))
print repr(t.big)
print repr(t.big(2, 16))
```

One nice thing about this magic object is that it becomes normal soon as you use it in a calculation (or call):

```
print type(t.big), type(t.big + 3), t.big + 3
print type(t.big), type(t.big(2, 3) + 9), t.big(2, 3) + 9
```

which results in

```
<class '__main__.CallableInt'> <type 'int'> 6
<class '__main__.CallableInt'> <type 'int'> 17
```

Comment: Indeed that is how it works, left-to-right evaluation, as it were. And it might be madness, but it's an interesting experiment.

Comment: @MattFeifarek: well, should you choose explore insanity remember that `__xxx__` methods are only looked up on the class, so you'll probably have to make custom class wrappers for whatever you want to return to take advantage of this style.

Comment: @MattFeifarek, Updated my answer to show an example of how this could work.

Comment: Now you're just messing with the `__str__` method of a custom class. Won't work with other types. And it's an awful solution

Comment: @JBernardo: um, I don't see a `__str__` method in my `CallableStr` class; and if by awful solution you mean one that works and answers the question, why yes it is awful.  As I said earlier, a custom class would be required for each type he wanted to have this work with.

Comment: @JBernardo: He didnt mess with the __str__ method. he just made a callable string object. It could be `class Callable<object>(<object>):`

Comment: You don't see because `print` makes a implicit call to it.

Comment: @JBernardo: okay, changed the `print` to `repr`, and also included an `int` subclass example -- hopefully you can see what's happening now.

Comment: Now you haven't changed anything. `repr` is string representation so you still have a custom object that looks like a string.

Comment: @JBernardo:  More example usage in place.  I encourage you to actually test the code so you know what you are talking about.

Comment: Thanks Ethan. Indeed, this be insanity. I can see a trick like this working if one was working with non-core types, like perhaps the Decimal() type, which is what I was thinking of working with. The problem with this particular technique (as illustrated) is that there's no relation between the things intrinsic value and the __call__ method upon it. So the utility is therefore low.

Comment: @MattFeifarek: If you are writing the `__call__` method then it's up to you use the intrinsic value of the object in that method.